# Type enter key is not responding in kermit why?

Tags: linux, enter, kermit

when i am trying to hit an enter when ever the kermit is used,it is not working.Even i re installed it.But it is not working for hitting enter to stop at u-boot and even for login credentials.Please suggest me the solution?

Comment: This question is probably better on the SuperUser or unix.StackExchange sites. That said, it sound like you have not configured the proper COM port in kermit of that *local echo* is disabled. Post to those sites for more answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have referred all the sites.The only answer we can say is use the usb-otg kermit,so that we can have login.But it is not possible to see the log during booting process.